# python directory forward and backward slashes mixing

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing a script for loading data in directories

```
PATH = os.getcwd()
# Define data path
data_path = PATH + '/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

img_data_list=[]

for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
#       x = x/255
        print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        img_data_list.append(x)
```

But i get this wierd error it didn't happen when i was running pgm earlier but now the forward and backward slashe mix up

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\vgg_test\vgg_trial/data/train/DR'  <<<<<<<<<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `/`, you can consider using `os.sep` which would provide the right path separator per operating system.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: can you tell why this problem arose it was working quite fine until a minute ago

Comment: The error you show indicates that the OS the code is running on is Windows.  Windows uses backward slash \, but occasionally can tolerate forward-slash-only path.  In your case, `os.getcwd()` may return a path that contains backward slash, and the code appends forward-slash in the path names, causing the system to be confused.